# Send an image through socket: ByteArrayOutputStream.size() return negative value (sometimes )

Tags: android

I am making server-client program, the server is Java on the computer and the client is android app (android studio) and I try to send image from the server to the client, and to show this image on the client's screen by ImageView. The problem is that sometimes its work and sometimes it doesn't work. Looks like there are times that ByteArrayOutputStream.size() return negative value in the client side in the variable len (that keep the length). When the return value is positive it works. Why am I getting negative values (sometimes)?

Server code:

```
    public class Server extends JFrame {
    BufferedImage bi,inputImage;
    JButton btn;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    public Server(){
        File imageFile = new File("ssss.PNG");
        try {
             bi = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.add(btn = new JButton("Send"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setSize(200, 180);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        try{
             serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
             socket = serverSocket.accept();
             in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
             out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                out.println("IMAGE");
               sendImage(new File("ssss.PNG"));
               // try {
                   // ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
                //} catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 //   e.printStackTrace();
              // }
            }
        });  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
                new Server();
    }
    public void sendImage(File file){
        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream ao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[dis.available()];
            while ((read = dis.read(buf)) > -1) {
                ao.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
            System.out.println("ao.size(): "+ao.size());
            out.writeInt(ao.size());
            out.write(ao.toByteArray());
            out.flush();
           // out.close();
           // dis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client code(android):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Socket socket;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public Scanner in;
    public TextView textView;
    public DataOutputStream dos=null;
    public DataInputStream dis=null;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public Bitmap bitmap;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 8000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.5.59";
    public static final String TAG="TAG";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }
    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "try to connect...");
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                Log.d(TAG, "connected1234");
                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    String response = in.nextLine();
                    if (response.startsWith("IMAGE")) {
                        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                        Log.d(TAG, "in: "+in);
                        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(in);
                        Log.d(TAG, "input: "+input);
                        byte[] data;
                        int len= input.readInt();
                        Log.d(TAG, "len: "+len);
                        data = new byte[len];
                        Log.d(TAG, "data: "+data);
                        if (len > 0) {
                            input.readFully(data,0,data.length);
                        }
                        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap: "+bitmap);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
len: -298696669
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.example.sendimageexample, PID: 17224
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -298696669
    at com.example.sendimageexample.MainActivity$ClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:80)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

client code:

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Socket socket;
public ImageView imageView;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 8000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.5.59";
public static final String TAG="TAG";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
   public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "try to connect...");
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            Log.d(TAG, "Adder: "+serverAddr);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            Log.d(TAG, "in: "+in);
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(in);
            Log.d(TAG, "input: "+input);
            Log.d(TAG, "connected1234");
                    byte[] data;
                    int len= input.readInt();//-298696669//17976
                    Log.d(TAG, "len: "+len);
                    data = new byte[len];
                    Log.d(TAG, "data: "+data);
                    if (len > 0) {
                        input.readFully(data,0,data.length);
                    }
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data 
                    .length);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap: "+bitmap);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                     public void run() {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos =new ByteArrayOutputStream();

             Bitmap bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image22);
            Log.d(TAG, "bitmap1: "+bitmap1);
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0,bos);
            byte []array=bos.toByteArray();
            OutputStream outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
            dos.writeInt(bos.size());
            dos.write(array,0,array.length);
            Log.d(TAG, "bos.size: "+bos.size());
            Log.d(TAG, "bos.array: "+bos.toByteArray());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

server code:

```
public class Server extends JFrame {
BufferedImage bi,inputImage;
JButton btn;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
Socket socket;
private Scanner in;
private PrintWriter out;
Server jframe=this;
public Server(){
    File imageFile = new File("ssss.PNG");
    try {
         bi = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.add(btn = new JButton("Send"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //this.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(200, 180);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    try{
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
         socket = serverSocket.accept();
         in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
         out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           sendImage(new File("ssss.PNG"));
           InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(inputStream);
           int size = dis.readInt();
           System.out.println("size: "+size);
           byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
           dis.readFully(imageAr);
           System.out.println("imageAr: "+imageAr);
           System.out.println("dis: "+dis);
           BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr));
           jframe.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
           revalidate();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           // try {
               // ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", socket.getOutputStream());
            //} catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             //   e.printStackTrace();
          // }
        }
    });  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {        
            new Server();
}
public void sendImage(File file){
    try {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream ao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[dis.available()];
        while ((read = dis.read(buf)) > -1) {
            ao.write(buf, 0, read);
            System.out.println("read: "+read);
            System.out.println("buf: "+buf);
        }
        System.out.println("ao.size(): "+ao.size());
        out.writeInt(ao.size());
        System.out.println("ao.toByteArray(): "+ao.toByteArray());
        out.write(ao.toByteArray());
        out.flush();
       // out.close();
       // dis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}